# Does not build apk file

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, dreamweaver

I'm new in mobile application. I'm using Dreamweaver CS5.5. Now I've tried to follow some video tutorial in youtube in building a mobile app, I've also installed the android SDK. But when I try to Build the files it always give me an error message 
[image]

But when i try to build and emulate is only shows the emulator.
The contents of buildlog.log are the following

```
WARNING: no icon was specified in app settings. using default.
WARNING: no splash screen was specified in app settings. using default.
Cloning seed app for Android
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\DWPHON~1\android\scripts\droidGap.bat "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\PhoneGapApp" "mobileSample" com.travelco.mob3 1.0 "C:\Andriod\android-sdk" 2
____________________
</DW>

C Created project directory: C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3

Created directory C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\src\com\travelco\mob3

Added file C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\src\com\travelco\mob3\DefaultActivity.java

Created directory C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\res

Created directory C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\bin

Created directory C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\libs

Created directory C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\res\values

Added file C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\res\values\strings.xml

Created directory C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\res\layout

Added file C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\res\layout\main.xml

Added file C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\AndroidManifest.xml

Added file C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\build.xml

Added file C:\Documents and Settings\PT\Desktop\com.travelco.mob3_Android\com.travelco.mob3\proguard-project.txt

CLONE SUCCESSFUL


<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\build.xml



-set-mode-check:



-set-debug-files:



-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1.0

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Andriod\android-sdk



-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mob3

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-pre-build:



-build-setup:

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mob3...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs

[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.

[gettarget] Platform Version: 2.2

[gettarget] API level:        8

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\res

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\gen

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\classes

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\dexedLibs

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mob3...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency] 

[dependency] ------------------

[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on



-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [aapt] C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'



BUILD FAILED

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:647: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:688: null returned: 1



Total time: 1 second


<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Andriod\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\Andriod\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
____________________
</DW>
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

List of devices attached 



Launching the Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Andriod\ANDROI~1\tools
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c "C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -partition-size 1024 -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -avd DW_AVD"
____________________
</DW>
WARNING: no icon was specified in app settings. using default.
WARNING: no splash screen was specified in app settings. using default.

<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\build.xml



-set-mode-check:



-set-debug-files:



-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1.0

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Andriod\android-sdk



-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mob3

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-pre-build:



-build-setup:

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mob3...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs

[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.

[gettarget] Platform Version: 2.2

[gettarget] API level:        8

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mob3...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency] 

[dependency] ------------------

[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on



-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [aapt] C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'



BUILD FAILED

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:647: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:688: null returned: 1



Total time: 1 second

OPERATION CANCELED
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Andriod\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\Andriod\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
____________________
</DW>
* server not running *


<DW>
____________________
ERROR: console error
    context: Dreamweaver.exe::GetExitCodeProcess
    code: 1
    message: Incorrect function.


____________________
</DW>

<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\build.xml



-set-mode-check:



-set-debug-files:



-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1.0

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Andriod\android-sdk



-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mob3

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-pre-build:



-build-setup:

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mob3...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs

[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.

[gettarget] Platform Version: 2.2

[gettarget] API level:        8

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mob3...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency] 

[dependency] ------------------

[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on



-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [aapt] C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'



BUILD FAILED

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:647: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:688: null returned: 1



Total time: 1 second


<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Andriod\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\Andriod\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
____________________
</DW>
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

List of devices attached 



Launching the Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Andriod\ANDROI~1\tools
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c "C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -partition-size 1024 -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -avd DW_AVD"
____________________
</DW>

<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\build.xml



-set-mode-check:



-set-debug-files:



-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1.0

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Andriod\android-sdk



-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mob3

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-pre-build:



-build-setup:

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mob3...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs

[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.

[gettarget] Platform Version: 2.2

[gettarget] API level:        8

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mob3...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency] 

[dependency] ------------------

[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on



-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [aapt] C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'



BUILD FAILED

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:647: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:688: null returned: 1



Total time: 1 second

OPERATION CANCELED
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Andriod\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
C:\Andriod\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
____________________
</DW>

<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Andriod\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~1\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\build.xml



-set-mode-check:



-set-debug-files:



-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1.0

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Andriod\android-sdk



-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mob3

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-pre-build:



-build-setup:

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mob3...

[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs

[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.

[gettarget] Platform Version: 2.2

[gettarget] API level:        8

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mob3...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries

[dependency] 

[dependency] ------------------

[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on



-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [aapt] C:\DOCUME~1\PT\Desktop\COMTRA~1.MOB\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'



BUILD FAILED

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:647: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Andriod\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:688: null returned: 1



Total time: 1 second
```

Can you help me solved this problem I can't find any solution about this problem is there anything I need to setup to be able to to create a mobile application?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
 package="com.travelco.mob3" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">   
  <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".DefaultActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: why can't you use eclipse for developing mobile applications for android?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file (obfuscated if needed)

Comment: Nezam I want to build a mobile application for an exsisting website. Is it easy to use eclipse than dreamweaver?

Comment: J.Romero I've posted the code for AndroidManifest.xml, can I asked what is the used of that file?

Comment: @khatz0406 show me the link which you followed

Comment: here it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXf1zyKQ5Hw

this is the other tutorial I follow http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip5NlD34GpE

Comment: try to use this <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/> if ti works i will explain it

Comment: @edwin where do i need to put those codes?

Comment: modify your code  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" /> to <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/> and place it above <supports-screens> tag

Comment: @edwin i've try what you said, i've edit the AndroidManifest.xml file and save it but it doesn't work but when i try to delete the existing folder when I build the app and build again it was successfully completed.

Comment: Can you make it clear ?? Did the change i suggest make any change or did it satisfy your need or it fail?

Comment: I think it doesn't I just deleted the existing folder in my desktop the click again the build function in my dreamweaver then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be on line 4 of AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'`
```

This attribute was introduced in API Level 9. Check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge

So you need to make sure your target is set to be higher than 9.

Comment: Can you explain further, I don't have much knowledge about mobile app. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your manifest file `android:minSdkVersion="5"` no`android:targetSdkVersion`

So when during compiling inside your `<supports-screens/>` tag some of attributes won't support in `SdkVersion="5"` .You will find out error

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'`
```

the solution use

`android:minSdkVersion="9"` or greater than 9 or

by setting `android:targetSdkVersion="9"`  or higher

SO Modify your manifest as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
 package="com.travelco.mob3" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".DefaultActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Or you can remove `<supports-screens/>` parameter which causing the error(But it's not a good approach.i won't recommend it)

Comment: i'll think it will not work because even I edit the AndriodManifest.xml it will not still create the apk file which is important to install the created mobile app. APK file will only be created once you click the build in Dreamweaver or any software that can be used for mobile application development.
But anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: I've already run the application properly using my dreamweaver. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Funny. I ran into this exact same problem.  The problem turned out to be that I had backed up my project directory to a CD.  When I did so these 'TRANS.TBL' files got added to every directory.  After I restored my project from the CD I had to remove all the `TRANS.TBL` files.  I build with `ant` not `eclipse` BTW.